# Accessing https web-service through Soap Android

Tags: android, web-services, https

I am accessing a https webservice hosted on server without certificate verification
when i run the web-service it shows me error like 
 and i am getiing something like this in logcat

```
WARN/InputManagerService(51): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@43cf47d8
```

why it is showing like this in Logcat

[image]

i want to access this web- service from my mobile through **SOAP** without no certifiate 
what i have done to access this web service is

```
URL="https://a.b.c.d/testservice/service.asmx"

SoapObject obj=new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,METHOD_NAME);


            obj.addProperty("p1",p2);
            obj.addProperty("p2",p2);


            SoapSerializationEnvelope ss_env=new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            ss_env.bodyOut=obj;
            ss_env.dotNet=true;
            ss_env.setOutputSoapObject(obj);
            HttpsTransportSE ah_tpt=new HttpsTransportSE(URL, 443, "", 30000);

            try{
                ah_tpt.call(SOAP_ACTION, ss_env);
                SoapPrimitive response=(SoapPrimitive)ss_env.getResponse();
```

i get the response **SocketTimeoutException** but when i access this web service through browser it is working , how can i get the main cause , is it the handshake Exception or what i am not clear about this , so need your help

Please help will be greatful 
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

try this code by increasing TimeOut because you are getting Socket timeOut Exception this i s because of Less timeout. It call web service in time interval we have defined here 3 sec if server through response in 3 sec then its okay otherwise it will through Socket TimeOut Exception. This may be the Reason.

```
  URL="https://a.b.c.d/testservice/service.asmx"

SoapObject obj=new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,METHOD_NAME);


        obj.addProperty("p1",p2);
        obj.addProperty("p2",p2);


        SoapSerializationEnvelope ss_env=new      SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        ss_env.bodyOut=obj;
        ss_env.dotNet=true;
        ss_env.setOutputSoapObject(obj);
        HttpsTransportSE ah_tpt=new HttpsTransportSE(URL, 443, "", 60000); // **Change   this.**

        try{
            ah_tpt.call(SOAP_ACTION, ss_env);
            SoapPrimitive response=(SoapPrimitive)ss_env.getResponse();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: this is not the reason i have also increased the time to 3 minutes but it is still giving the same error , idont know about the rest of the code is it ok ?

Comment: post your stacktrace maybe through that i will help you.

Comment: 03-18 12:27:26.123: WARN/InputManagerService(51): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@43d4f6b0

Comment: when i click on the button to use web service i get the following line  in logcat

Comment: try to figure out your error from this links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3140524/geting-window-already-focused-ignoring-focus-gain-of-com-android-internal-vie

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12209664/window-already-focused-ignoring-focus-gain-of-com-android-internal-view-iinput

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14504709/warning-window-already-focused-ignoring-focus-gain-of-com-android-internal-view

hope this helps.

Comment: have you declared your Activity in AndroidManifest.xml? if not try adding `<activity android:name=".mainPage" />` in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49918/discussion-between-i-n-e-f-and-raghav-chopra)

Comment: i have already done that if i would have not done that i would not be able to see my activity , so this is not the correct solution or suggestion